# this is a sorting array by frequency in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

This code works fine for me, but when I upload it to the "Geeks For geeks" website, it gives me an error and says that this code does not work in many test cases, knowing that I tried it even at state 120..Is there a problem with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 //code
 int t ;
 int a=0;
 int count =0;
 int temp=0 ;
 int element ;
 int E_Temp=0;

 scanf("%d",&t);
 while(t--){
     int n ;
     scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    while(a<n){
        element=0;
        temp=0;
        for(int i=a;i<n;++i){//start from a no from 0 ***
            for(int j=a;j<n;++j){
                if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            
                if(count==temp){
                    if(arr[i]<element){
                    element=arr[i];
                    temp=count;
                    }
                    
                }
                else if(count>temp){
                    element=arr[i];
                    temp=count;//this because i will make the count"0" to make another process
                }
    
            
            count=0;
        }
        //sort the element ..
    
        for(int i=a;i<n;++i){//imprtant this constrans ....
         if (arr[i]!=element){//must check that not equal
         
          for(int j=i;j<n;++j){
                if (arr[j]==element){
                    E_Temp=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=E_Temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
         }  
         
        }
    
          a=a+temp;
          
    }
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        
    }
printf("\n");
 }
return 0 ;  
}
```

I tried it in all cases in the C language on gcc
this the link  https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sorting-elements-of-an-array-by-frequency/0/?problemType=full&page=1&query=problemTypefullpage1#

Comment: can you add link of problem of geeks for geeks?

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sorting-elements-of-an-array-by-frequency/0/?problemType=full&page=1&query=problemTypefullpage1#

Comment: this the link  https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sorting-elements-of-an-array-by-frequency/0/?problemType=full&page=1&query=problemTypefullpage1#

Comment: Does the failed test show you the expected vs. actual results? What are they?

Comment: Your output is incorrect: you're printing out extra lines ("Enter the element"), which will mess up automated testing, *and* you're printing the sorted elements line by line. The exercise requires the elements to be printed on one line, separated by a space (see the example). So you're output should be `t` lines of `n` space-separated numbers.

Comment: You should give sample input and sample out.

Comment: The first time `if(arr[i]==arr[j]){` is exected, it is `if(arr[0]==arr[0]){ count++;`.  Is this intended?

Comment: My friend, I have tried everything you say, I have tried all the possibilities and I tested this code more than once and it was correct, but when I upload it to the site, at first it is correct, but when I send it and the program does the test with more values, it gives me an error…” I understand that it must be Income and output comply with the requirements of the report, but the problem has not yet been resolved
Can someone test this code for me and show me what the problem is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables a and count should be initialized to 0 before the nested loop while (a<n)